# I am 5'8 I ride around bad roads what is the ideal handle bar height for me

Tags: riding-position

I am 5'8 and I ride around bad roads what is the ideal handle bar height for me.

Comment: This question can't be answered without looking at you on your bike. The answer will depend on your arm length, top-tube length, stem length, handlebar shape, your comfort, what kind of riding you're doing, etc.

Comment: Your cannot be answered in its current form. You'll get a better response if you rewrite it to ask *how* you can determine the best handle bar position for you.

Comment: What style of bike is it?  How old are you?  How flexible are you?  What part of you hurts given your current setup ?

Comment: Do you mean roads with bad surfaces? Roads with bad traffic?

Answer (score 1):

The best height for you is what is most comfortable for you - we can't tell you that.

Some people like the bars well above their saddle for and upright position, some others prefer them about even, some racer types like their bars much lower than the saddle.

A bike that is uncomfortable will not be ridden, so you need to figure out what your preferred position is, and the heights will be part of that.